# Angular 2 Model binding

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Hi I have a setup like following. What happens is that, whenever I change either the Kelvin or Celsius field, I get weird outputs like `*1000` of what I entered, or weirder things that did not make sense to me so far.

Anyone able to help out? I am quite new to Angular 2. I guess this has to do with how I did the binding.

```
class Temperature {
  kelvin: number;

  constructor(kelvin: number) {
    this.kelvin = kelvin;
  }

  getKelvin(): number {
    return this.kelvin;
  }

  setKelvin(kelvin: number) {
    this.kelvin = kelvin;
  }

  getCelsius(): number {
    return this.kelvin - 273.15;
  }

  setCelsius(celsius: number) {
    this.kelvin = celsius + 273.15;
  }
}

export class ConverterComponent implements OnInit {
  temperature: Temperature;

  constructor() {
    this.temperature = Temperature.fromKelvin(21);
  }

  onKelvinChange(kelvin: number) {
    this.temperature.setKelvin(kelvin);
  }

  onCelsiusChange(celsius: number) {
    this.temperature.setCelsius(celsius);
  }


<input id="temperature-kelvin" type="number" class="form-control" [ngModel]="temperature.getKelvin()" (input)="onKelvinChange($event.target.value)" />
<input id="temperature-celsius" type="number" class="form-control" [ngModel]="temperature.getCelsius()" (input)="onCelsiusChange($event.target.value)" />
```

Comment: I see a Kelvin input and a Celsius input, but no Fahrenheit input. Also, I don't see the definition for `Temperature.fromCelsius`.

Comment: Sorry, I added only an excerpt of the code. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it myself and it is a bit embarrassing. Typescripts method parameters are not translated in a typesafe way to JS. So what happens in following method is not a sum of numbers, but the concatenation of strings, as `celsius` comes in as string from the input field.

```
setCelsius(celsius: number) {
  this.kelvin = celsius + 273.15;
}
```

That can easily be resolved by adding a `+` as unary operator in front of the variable:

```
setCelsius(celsius: number) {
  this.kelvin = +celsius + 273.15;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. You don't need [(ngModel)] because you are receiving the input value in Onchange.

**Temperature Model**

```
class Temperature {
  kelvin: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  getKelvin(): number {
    return this.kelvin;
  }

  setKelvin(kelvin: number) {
    this.kelvin = kelvin;
  }

  getCelsius(): number {
    return this.kelvin - 273.15;
  }

  setCelsius(celsius: number) {
    this.kelvin = celsius + 273.15;
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class ConverterComponent implements OnInit {
  temperature: Temperature;

  constructor() {
    this.temperature = new Temperature();
  }

  onKelvinChange(event) {
    this.temperature.setKelvin(event.target.value);
  }

  onCelsiusChange(event) {
    this.temperature.setCelsius(event.target.value);
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="temperature-kelvin" type="number" class="form-control" (keyup)="onKelvinChange($event)" />
<input id="temperature-celsius" type="number" class="form-control" (keyup)="onCelsiusChange($event)" />
```

Comment: I know, but that actually did not resolve the issue.